# Photo is lost and Unpinned when app restarts

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse `pinInBackground` feature to save information that will later be synced with parse, but a part of that information is a photo that has been taken , but when I restart the app before the info has synced with Parse , the image is lost. 
How do I not lose the picture when the app has been restarted.
Must I save it locally? If so , where and how?
Thank you in advance , let me know if any of my code is needed.

```
//Here I pin the picture in the background
@IBAction func cameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let pickedImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.5)
    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)


    locationLogs["photo"] = imageFile
    locationLogs.pinInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (success) {
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }else{
            println("error= \(error)")
        }
    }
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

//Query it 
func queryAll() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"LocationLogs")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (NSArray results, NSError error) in
        if error == nil && results != nil {
            println("array = \(results)" )
            self.tableData = results!
            self.loggedItemsTableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            println("An error has occured= \(error)")
        }
    })
}

//Save and unpin it 
 @IBAction func syncAllButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFObject.saveAllInBackground(self.tableData as [AnyObject], block: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {

            PFObject.unpinAllInBackground(self.tableData as [AnyObject])

            println("Pinned Data has successfully been saved")


        }else{
            println("error= \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you put up the code that you are using to try and retrieve the pinned data with?

Answer (score 0):

Parse saves the photo in the `tmp/` directory , and when the app is restarted , the `tmp/` is wiped.
Save the picture to the `Documents/` directory and when you sync , pull the picture from `Documents/` and then save it. 
I dont know the code, so if someone can give an explanation, That Would be greeeeaaat